# Compress Images that are already uploaded

Tags: 7, media

I working on a website which has a content type. The content type contains an image field. Thousands of images uploaded already. Because image size is very big, there is requirement to compress the size of images.

I found a module [Image API Optimize](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize), but this module works only when a new image is uploaded. But my requirement is that I want to compress the images which are already uploaded.

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A module like [Max Image Size](https://www.drupal.org/project/max_image_size) will resize the original images that have already been uploaded, but I don't believe it is possible to also use an optimization on the images when they are resized.  You can only specify a new maximum width and height.